# How to assign a default value in a column based on another column's value?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, default-value

I want a column in my database to have a default value which is the same for every row, however the last characters should be the primary key of the row.

Is this possible to implement using PHP/MySQL?

e.g(I want the Link column to have the default value)

```
+----+----------------------------+
| ID |            Link            |
+----+----------------------------+
|  1 | edit_item.php?id=1         |
|  2 | edit_item.php?id=2         |
|  3 | edit_item.php?id=3         |
+----+----------------------------+
```

Thanks very much for any help!

Comment: Why store the link when you can generate it in queries or on the client-side?

Comment: @siride I am using a javascript plugin called JSGANTT which generates a GANTT chart based on a MySQL table. When you click on a task on the GANTT chart,it will open a window based on the link column which I have specified above. I am unfortunatley not experienced enough to change this behaviour as I am very new to js/MySQL/PHP, and am looking for a workaround in the meanwhile.

Comment: I think the workaround would be to figure out how to generate links directly. That's going to help you in the long-run anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of insert you need to insert and update your record.

Firstly insert your record and then get last inserted id and then update record eg:

```
<?php 

$sql = "INSERT INTO TableName(Link) VALUES ('edit_item.php')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) { 
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
} else {
    $id = mysql_insert_id();

    mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE TableName SET Link='edit_item.php?id=".$id."' WHERE id=$id); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Evan, this worked exactly how I needed it too. Note: I had to use mysqli_insert_id($con) due to my PHP version, if anyone is having trouble doing the same.

Comment: I believe you mean @user3792362, I just edited his answer. :)

Comment: You're right, thanks alot @user3790350 for the answer and Evan for the edit, appreciate the help! :)

Answer (score -1):

You can't dynamically set the default, but you can definitely use some sort of replacement with **printf()**, such as the following:

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE links (
    id   INT  PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    link TEXT DEFAULT "edit_item.php?id=%d"
);
```

And then in PHP, replace the %d with the ID using **printf()**,

```
<?php

// Let's assume it's an array with this format:
// ['id' => 1, 'link' => 'edit_item.php?id=%d']
$row = yourSelectCommandThatReturnsAnObject();

// In this case, $row['id'] will replace the %d.
$link = printf($row['link'], $row['id']);
```

You can check out [the PHP docs for printf()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) for some more info.

Comment: If you can use printf, just generate the link directly. This is useless indirection.

Comment: I'm answering the user's question, not providing coding advice. And as the user stated it's currently a workaround.

Comment: my point is that if the user is already in a situation where they can use `printf()` after the query to sub out parameters, they're in a situation where they can also safely generate the link directly. The problem the user appears to be facing is that they have no control over what happens to the results of the query, which also means they won't be able to use printf either.